# implementing socket.io with wordpress

Tags: plugin-development

was just curious if anyone has any insight on how to implement real time features into wordpress, specifically with socket.io, preferably with my own plugin (or without). i have a project idea that i have used similar features outside of wordpress with socket.io, but the backend stuff is tripping me up a bit and i need some direction.

i did come across this video of guillermo rauch demoing socket io on wordpress and he makes it seem easy, but he's going too fast and i don't understand what socket-redis is, which seems to make it work. he starts demoing a little before halfway through the video: https://wordpress.tv/2014/11/03/guillermo-rauch-realtime-communication-with-socket-io-and-wordpress/

there is also a udemy class i found where they implemented zeroMQ and express.

i haven't found much else but these two, was wondering what the differences were and if one was better than the other, or if there are other ways i can do this. thanks for any help.

Comment: Welcome to WordPress Development but what exactly is your question?

Comment: the jist of it is using socket io with wordpress.  how do you do it? i'm not finding a whole lot on how to implement it. i'm more curious on how he did it in that video link i posted. i wasn't sure if this was the right place to ask.